# Get everything from an array to a variable

Tags: python

Here I select all the emails of users and put them into 1 array:

````
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sqlEmail = "SELECT epost FROM brukere WHERE notification = 'YES'"
mycursor.execute(sqlEmail)
result = mycursor.fetchall()

emailList = []

for row in result:
    emailList.append(row[0])

print("Email list for current script: ", emailList[0], emailList[1], emailList[2])```
````

I want to put every email into the senders list but the only way I figured to do it was like this

```
gmail_user = 'anonymous' # this is the email sending it
sent_from = gmail_user
to = [emailList[0], emailList[1], emailList[2]] #<
subject = 'Temperature is over 28C!!!'
body = """
```

Here I want it to take 1 by one from the array so if there are new emails added it inserts them automatically, also if 1 email is taken off the email list in the database it crashes because its hard coded to having 3 emails from the database.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Just use `to = emailList`. I don't know why you are extracting elements to create a new list, if what you want is the whole list.

Comment: You already have the list you need. Don't build another. `to = emailList`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, i actually figured it out already. im not creating another list btw its just choosing from the list. im new to python hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-lists-in-python-4-different-ways/) on how to print arrays. Don't see why you're hardcoding the three values if you want to print the entire list. Furthermore, in `to = [emailList[0], emailList[1], emailList[2]]` you're basically taking the separate values from an array and putting them back into a new array? If you can already pass in an array then just pass emailList as is.

If you're trying to specify which range of your array to pass in, you can specify your start and end indices. [More info.](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/)

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
print(a[1:3])
>>>1 2 3
print(a[:2])
>>>0,1,2
```